# Aysnc convert object to coroutine. Load object fields

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have the following function

```
async def get_page(self, browser):
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page._client.send("Emulation.clearDeviceMetricsOverride")
    await page.setViewport(
        {"width": 2560, "height": 1600, "deviceScaleFactor": 4})
    return page
```

Along with the following test

```
def test_get_page(page_test_args):
    client = VjsClient()
    browser = client.get_browser()
    page = client.get_page(browser)
    assert page._viewport == page_test_args
```

When my code hits

```
assert page._viewport == page_test_args
```

I run into this error

```
    def test_get_page(page_test_args):
        client = VjsClient()
        browser = client.get_browser()
        page = client.get_page(browser)
>       assert page._viewport == page_test_args
E       AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute '_viewport'
```

How do I resolve this so that I can keep accessing my pages fields and keep the async function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async def get_page(self, browser):
```

`async def` here means that call of `get_page` will returns an `asyncio` [coroutine](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines). To actually execute `get_page` and get result you should [await](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#awaitables) for this coroutine.

Your test should be altered this way:

```
page = await client.get_page(browser)
```

Note however that if you await for something inside function this function (`test_get_page`) must be coroutine itself (must be defined with `async def`) and awaited somewhere to be executed.

It means you should use [pytest-asyncio](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-asyncio) in addition to plain `pytest` as shown [here](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-asyncio#pytestmarkasyncio).